# What's the easiest java multiplayer network game?

Tags: java

We are instructed to create a Java multiplayer game, and yet I still have no idea what is the easiest multiplayer game for a Java beginner like me.

Any suggestions would help a lot.  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a multiplayer hangman where you bound the number of words a user can try to those contained in /usr/share/dict/words.  Hangman is nice since it is simply a text based game where determining when the game state implies a win or a loss is extremely simple (either the number of wrong guesses has been made or all letters in the answer string have been guessed).

Answer (score 5):

Multiplayer tic-tac-toe would be trivial to build the game logic, and allow you to concentrate on the multiplayer / networking aspect.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Slomojo, multiplayer Tic-Tac-Toe is a good starting point. In fact, I found that a third-party SDK named Skiller actually provides it as a free multiplayer game with source code. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about pong maybe? really depends on the genre of games you're interested in.

Check out a related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571460/multiplayer-browser-game-java).

Answer (score 0):

Casino games are simple and multiplayer.  Roulette, for example, is really very simple.  Blackjack and Craps are a bit more complex.